# How to get Azure IoT Hub Device's connection string programatically using .Net C#

Tags: c#, .net, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I've an scenario where need to get Azure IoT Hub device's connection string by passing device id programmatically using .NET C#.

We can connect to Azure IoT Hub using connection string using Microsoft.Azure.Devices, Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client packages and we can send messages to the devices.

but, In my case, I have to provide device access policies to the customer to send messages directly to that device/device id by using that device's connection string.

[image]

Here, I need to get Primary and Secondary connection string by passing Device ID programmatically in .NET C#.

Answer (score 4):

> I followed the below steps to send messages directly to that device/device id by using device connection string and to get Primary and Secondary connection string.

- Create a IoT Hub in Azure portal

[image]

- Create a Device in the IoT hub you created

[image]

[image]

- In visual studio code enter the below code.

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices;

namespace GetDeviceConnectionString
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
   
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the device id:");
                string deviceId = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Enter the connection string for your IoT hub:");
                string iotHubConnectionString = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the iotHubName:");
                string iotHubName = Console.ReadLine();
                RegistryManager registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(iotHubConnectionString);

                var device = registryManager.GetDeviceAsync(deviceId).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Primary key: " + device.Authentication.SymmetricKey.PrimaryKey);
                Console.WriteLine("Secondary Key: " + device.Authentication.SymmetricKey.SecondaryKey);

               
                Console.WriteLine(" Primary Connection String  : " + " HostName = " + iotHubName+ " .azure - devices.net; DeviceId = " + deviceId+"; SharedAccessKey = " + device.Authentication.SymmetricKey.PrimaryKey);
                Console.WriteLine("Secondary Connection String : " + " HostName = " + iotHubName + " .azure - devices.net; DeviceId = " + deviceId + "; SharedAccessKey = " + device.Authentication.SymmetricKey.SecondaryKey);

                
                registryManager.CloseAsync().Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the message to send:");
                string message = Console.ReadLine();

                ServiceClient serviceClient = ServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(iotHubConnectionString);
                serviceClient.SendAsync(deviceId, new Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Message(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message))).Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("Message sent successfully!");
                Console.ReadLine();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex+"the details are not valid" );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Enter the required details to connect to the IoT Hub. For more details refer Programming Microsoft Azure Service Fabric - Pearsoncmg.

[image]

[image]